# Eclipse giving an error about not returning an integer

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, binary-search

The following code is supposed to do a recursive binary search for a card in a array of cards. Eclipse gives an error that the method does not return an integer.

```
public static int binaryrSearch(Card[] cards, Card target , int low , int high)
{
    if (high<low)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    int mid = (low+high)/2;
    int comp = cards[mid].compareTo(target);
    if(comp==0)
    {
        return mid;
    }else if(comp<0)
    {
        return binaryrSearch(cards , target , mid+1 , high);
    }else if (comp>0)
    {
        return binaryrSearch(cards , target , low , mid-1);
    }
}
```

the compareto method:

```
public int compareTo(Card that){
    if(this.suit<that.suit)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if(this.suit>that.suit)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if(this.rank<that.rank)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if(this.rank>that.rank)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the exception you are being thrown?

Comment: You can't only conditionally return. Even though it could never pass through those 3 conditions without returning, the IDE doesn't know that.

Comment: This method return a result of type int

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your if-else-if statements cover all possible values of `comp` (`comp==0`, `comp<0` and `comp>0`), you should change the last else if :

```
else if (comp>0)
```

to else :

```
else
```

This way the compiler will realize that your method always returns a value.

```
...
if (comp==0) {
    return mid;
} else if (comp<0) {
    return binaryrSearch(cards , target , mid+1 , high);
} else {
    return binaryrSearch(cards , target , low , mid-1);
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add return statement at end of `binaryrSearch` method

```
public static int binaryrSearch(Card[] cards, Card target , int low , int high)
{
   ....
   ....
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a return Statement at the end of the method:

```
    public static int binaryrSearch(Card[] cards, Card target , int low , int high)
{
    if (high<low)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    int mid = (low+high)/2;
    int comp = cards[mid].compareTo(target);
    if(comp==0)
    {
        return mid;
    }else if(comp<0)
    {
        return binaryrSearch(cards , target , mid+1 , high);
    }else if (comp>0)
    {
        return binaryrSearch(cards , target , low , mid-1);
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both methods , adding a return statement which is never reached and removing the last if worked. Thank you guys for your immediate help.